# Merge Git branches based on a specified pair of commits as the common base

Tags: git, merge

Is it possible to merge branches in Git based on a specified pair of commits as the common base?

**Scenario:**

Two separate Git repositories, '*ours*' and '*theirs*'.

'*Theirs*' was created using the working copy (files only) from '*ours*' at a known point in time. The initial commit in '*theirs*' is adding a snapshot of '*our*' files.

We now want to merge '*theirs*' into '*ours*':

```
git remote add theirs <their repository path>
git pull theirs <their branch> --allow-unrelated-histories
```

`git merge` will look for a common ancestor on which to base the merge. However, there's no common commit between '*ours*' and '*theirs*'.

As we can find the commit in '*ours*' where the working copy matched the initial commit in '*theirs*', I'm thinking Git should be able to sensibly start the merge, but we'll need to instruct Git to treat the two specific commits as the common base.

Comment: The `git merge` has also option `--allow-unrelated-histories`.

Comment: max630's answer—essentially, create a parent graft to lie about the commit history (it's OK because [*this* lie is true!](http://libraries.udmercy.edu/find/special_collections/digital/cfa/index.php?fl_id=19822))—is the way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'Theirs' was created using the working copy (files only) from 'ours' at a known point in time. The initial commit in 'theirs' is adding a snapshot of 'our' files.

Probably, in your case the best option would be to add replacement with fake parent to the corresponding "ours" commit:

```
git replace --edit <THEIRS_INIT>
```

add there "`parent <OURS_COMMIT>`" line to the headers, then save

You can remove the replacement after the merge is done.

Comment: That's a use of `replace` I hadn't considered.  Personally I don't like where that leaves the history, but it is another reasonably simple option

Comment: If you're going to use replace on a commit, I'd recommend using the [--graft](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace#git-replace---graftltcommitgtltparentgt82308203) syntax instead.

Answer (score 0):

So let's start by getting all the objects in one repo, before worrying about the merge

```
git fetch theirs
```

And so now you have

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G <--(master)

d -- H -- I -- J <--(theirs/master)
```

The content (`TREE`) at `d` is identical to the content at `D`.

Now you want to merge `H` through `J` into `master` treating `D` as the merge base.  You can probably come up with some scripted combination of plumbing commands that would do literally that.  But I wouldn't.

Instead, I'd think about how best to combine the histories.  The easiest way is to rebase `H` through `J` onto `D`.  Similar, but less processing / less chance for something weird to happen, would be to reparent `H` instead of rebasing.  (Because `d` and `D` have the same content, the result should be the same with either operation.)

To reparent `H` you would use `git filter-branch` with the `--parent-filter` option.  You'd need to look up the commit ID (SHA) values for `d` and `D`, and then maybe use a `sed` script that replaces the `d` ID with the `D` ID.  See the `filter-branch` docs for details; I'm pretty sure there's an example for exactly this case.

If you don't want to deal with that, like I said a rebase *should* be equivalent in this case.  You still need an expression that resolves to `D` - such as `master~3` in the example, or the commit ID is fine - and one that resolves to `d` - `theirs/master~3` in the example.

```
git checkout theirs/master
git checkout -b temp
git rebase --onto master~3 theirs/master~3
```

This gives you

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G <--(master)
                \
                 H' -- I' -- J' <--(temp)

d -- H -- I -- J <--(theirs/master)
```

Now you may just want to merge `temp` into `master` and discard `theirs/master`; but the potential down-side would be that `H'`, `I'`, and `J'` are new commits (with new ID values, etc.), so if you're going to keep maintaining the `theirs` repo and want to migrate changes back and forth, this approach would leave you with the same problem at the next migration.

So if you are keeping `theirs` around, you can adjust as follows:

Ideally in that case you'd want to use the original commits from `theirs`, but that's not terribly easy to do.  What you could do instead is make a sort of "phony merge" of `theirs/master` into `temp` before merging `temp` to `master`.

```
git checkout temp
git merge -s ours theirs/master
```

Now you have

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G <--(master)
                \
                 H' -- I' -- J' -- JJ <--(temp)
                                  /
                  d -- H -- I -- J <--(theirs/master)
```

`JJ` could appear to be an "evil merge" - its content is not the natural/default result of merging `J'` with `J`.  But given those histories, such a merge should conflict - i.e. there shouldn't *be* such a thing as a "natural/default result" for such a merge.  So it's not as troubling.

This means that `J`, `J'`, and `JJ` all have the same content, and merging `temp` to `master` should still get you the correct result

```
A -- B -- C -- D --- E --- F --- G --- M <--(master)
                \                     /
                 H' -- I' -- J' -- JJ <--(temp)
                                  /
                  d -- H -- I -- J <--(theirs/master)
```

At this point you can delete `temp`.

The purpose of keeping `d`, `H`, `I`, `J`, and `JJ` is, like I said, to facilitate future updates from `theirs`.  On a future fetch you might get

```
A -- B -- C -- D --- E --- F --- G --- M -- N -- O -- P <--(master)
                \                     /
                 H' -- I' -- J' -- JJ 
                                  /
                  d -- H -- I -- J -- K -- L <--(theirs/master)
```

from this state, you can simply merge `theirs/master` into `master` as git will calculate that `J` is the merge base.